# Disabling Pattern Unlock when Power Button Pressed

Tags: lock-screens, app-widgets

I've just downloaded and installed DashClock onto my Nexus 5. I really like the functionality - but I found its usefulness is diminished somewhat by the fact that the pattern unlock automatically appears. What I want is for all the information to be there when I press the power button and my phone is locked and have to swipe up for the unlock gesture - not the converse as it is by default - swipe the pattern unlock down to see the full widget. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Android's lockscreen widget by design comes minimized, and you have to manually maximize it.  There is no way to configure it otherwise.

That said, some custom ROMs (e.g. CyanogenMod, AOKP) offer the functionality to enable showing the expanded lockscreen widget when the screen is turned on:

[image]

Of course, you will need to unlock your phone's bootloader and flash custom firmware in order to obtain this feature.